# Google Slides, R, d3: Insert Interactive Visualizations

Tags: r, d3.js

I have created an interactive visualization using R and D3 and would like to insert it into a presentation while maintaining its interactivity. Is this possible?

Minimum working example (MWE:

```
library(networkD3)

# https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata//flare.json
URL <- paste0(
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
  "master/JSONdata//flare.json")
Flare <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
diagonalNetwork(List = Flare, fontSize = 10, opacity = 0.9)
```

Presently, I am trying to insert the visualization into a Google Slides presentation but I am open to other slide presentation solutions (e.g. LaTeX/Beamer, PowerPoint, etc.) as long as it achieves my goals. It is preferable to avoid having to mess around with JavaScript directly, hence why I am using the `networkD3` package for `R`.

Aside: a problem with the Beamer route is that [the themes are quite ugly](https://mpetroff.net/files/beamer-theme-matrix/) and I have yet to see a pretty Beamer presentation.

Comment: I suspect this can done with `xaringan`. Is your code working as is? Where is `Flare` defined?

Comment: I will look into `xaringan`. Yes, my code works as is. `Flare.json` is here: # https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata//flare.json

Comment: When I run it I get this: `Error in diagonalNetwork(List = Flare, fontSize = 10, opacity = 0.9) : 
  object 'Flare' not found"`. I presume I should do something to assign the URL to the Flare object, like `Flare <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)`?

Comment: You might also look at `r2d3`: https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/

Comment: @JonSpring yes. copy-paste error, sorry about that